# doctrine override default finder methods for all entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

There is a way to override the default finder methods for all entity repository
for exemple this is the default methode `findBy` in Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository

```
 public function findBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null, $limit = null, $offset = null)
    {
        $persister = $this->_em->getUnitOfWork()->getEntityPersister($this->_entityName);
        return $persister->loadAll($criteria, $orderBy, $limit, $offset);
    }
```

But my need is something like this

```
 public function findBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null, $limit = null, $offset = null)
    {
        $persister = $this->_em->getUnitOfWork()->getEntityPersister($this->_entityName);
        $criteria['foo'] = 'bar';
        return $persister->loadAll($criteria, $orderBy, $limit, $offset);
    }
```

I want create a service to override this method by modifying the criteria array and adding some custom criteria attribute if needed.
I know that I can override the repository for every entity but my project has been enlarged and for now I want a practical solution to avoid changing in all entity repository.

Comment: Hello, why you can't inject customs `$criteria` to this existing method ?

Comment: This is sick ;) use [filters](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/filters.html) instead.

Comment: @Weenesta-MathieuDormeval I have a large project, and I want avoid injecting customs criteria on around thirty methods in the whole project

Comment: @emix with your answer I just finished implementing a listener working with the my custom filter, thx a lot :)

Comment: Glad I could help. Kindly upvote and accept my answer then :) good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to the answer of @emix this is more detailed solution

Now let's create the annotation. This will be added to the class to indicate which fields that will be filtered by doctrine.

```
/**
 * @Annotation
 * @Target("CLASS")
 */
final class CenterSelector
{
    public $centerFieldName;
}
```

And use it in your class

```
 /**
 * @CenterSelector(centerFieldName="you-name-field")
 */
class CommercialPiece{
   protected $you-name-field;
}
```

Create your Filter class that extends from SQLFilter

```
class CenterFilter extends SQLFilter
{
    protected $reader;

    public function addFilterConstraint(ClassMetadata $targetEntity, $targetTableAlias)
    {

        if (empty($this->reader)) {
            return '';
        }

        // The Doctrine filter is called for any query on any entity
        // Check if the current entity is (marked with an annotation)
        $centerSelector = $this->reader->getClassAnnotation(
            $targetEntity->getReflectionClass(),
            CenterSelector::class
        );

        if (!$centerSelector) {
            return '';
        }

        // FieldName parameter in annotation
        $fieldName = $centerSelector->centerFieldName;

        try {
            $mySelector= $this->getParameter('my-selector');
        } catch (\InvalidArgumentException $e) {
            // No my-selector has been defined
            return '';
        }

        if (empty($fieldName) || empty($mySelector)) {
            return '';
        } else{
            var_dump($mySelector);
            // Add the Where clause in the request
            $query = sprintf('%s.%s = %s', $targetTableAlias, $fieldName, $mySelector);
        }

        return $query;
    }

    public function setAnnotationReader(Reader $reader)
    {
        $this->reader = $reader;
    }
}
```

And I created a listener onKernelRequest

```
  public function __construct(
        ObjectManager $em, 
        SessionInterface $session, 
        Reader $reader)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->session = $session;
        $this->reader = $reader;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $globalSelector = $this->session->get('my-global-selector');           
        $filter = $this->em->getFilters()->enable('center_filter');
        $filter->setParameter('my-selector', $globalSelector );
        $filter->setAnnotationReader($this->reader);
    }
```

Finally don't forget to add this in config.yml

```
orm:
    entity_managers:
        default:
            auto_mapping: true
            filters:
                center_filter:
                    class: your-name-space\Filter\CenterFilter
                    enabled: true
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make a class that extends ServiceEntityRepository and in that class define all the classes you wish to override. Then finally you will need to update all your repositories to extend this new class instead of the ServiceEntityRepository.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't do it this way. Embrace [Doctrine Filters](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/filters.html). Using one you can introduce any kind of logic globally to all of your queries.